# Flex - splash screen for a desktop app (non mobile app)

Tags: flash, apache-flex, desktop-application, splash-screen, preloader

I'm using fb4linux, I'm developing a non-mobile (i.e. desktop application) and I would like to add a splash screen to it.

I've added mobilecomponents.swc to the library path, and the application starts like this:

```
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
   xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
   xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
   width="400" height="400" xmlns:local="*"
   preloader="spark.preloaders.SplashScreen"
   splashScreenImage="@Embed('assets/splashscreen.png')"
   splashScreenMinimumDisplayTime="1500">
```

When I debug it, no splash scren is shown and I get the following error:

```
ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable flash.display::StageAspectRatio is not defined.
    at spark.preloaders::SplashScreen/prepareSplashScreen()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\mobilecomponents\src\spark\preloaders\SplashScreen.as:340]
    at spark.preloaders::SplashScreen/Stage_resizeHandler()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\mobilecomponents\src\spark\preloaders\SplashScreen.as:407]
```

The problem seems to be triggered by the line that sets the preloader, because if I remove it, the error is gone (although no splash screen is shown either).

Any ideas how to make it work?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you including mobilecomponents.swc for a Flex app?  These address orientation change and are based on DPI for skins.

Comment: Because of what it says here: [Add a splash screen to an application - help page](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/WSa122979b4619725672e48c412a3e152164-8000.html#WSeed33909c77d7dca62868183131aee86625-8000)

_**Note:** To use the splash screen in a desktop application, set the Application.preloader property to spark.preloaders.SplashScreen. Also add the frameworks\libs\mobile\mobilecomponents.swc to the library path of the application._

Comment: It sounds like it doesn't have a airglobal.swc, (I looked through SplashScreen source, Ctrl+Shift+T, and see the import/use of StageAspectRatio but import is from airglobal.swc.  Also something to be cautious of Linux only has support for AIR up to 2.6.   Also check out the docs http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/StageAspectRatio.html

Comment: I tried using airglobal.swc but still didn't work.
Yes, you're right: Flex 4.5.1 SDK contains AIR 2.6 support (see [4.5.1 SDK release notes](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-builder/release-note/release-notes-flex-4-5.html)) Why is that a problem? StageAspectRatio is only included in later versions?
Thanks!

Comment: Any other ideas on how to do a splash screen using this SDK? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You should add

`import [install folder]\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\sdks\4.6.0\frameworks\libs\mobile`

to your build path.